# Pointers to class member that are pointers to classes with the same base

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
class Base { ... };
class Bool : public Base { bool val; }
class Size : public Base { long val; }
class More : public Base { void* val; }

class Test {
    static Base* Test::* fields;
public:
    Bool* flag;
    Size* size;
    More* data;
};
```

The goal is to be able to use `fields` to go through the data members, but I can't
`Base* Test::*(Test::fields) = &Test::flag;` because of the error (clang here, gnu++11) `Cannot initialize a variable of type 'Base *Test::*' with an rvalue of type 'Bool *Test::*'` though `Bool*` can be implicitly cast to `Base*`. Is there a solution?

Comment: What is the underlying and actual problem you try to solve this way? Why do you need pointers to the classes? Why do you need a `fields` pointer? How would that solve the underlying problem? This question in its current form is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Say there are two types, `X` and `Y`, and `X` can be implicitly converted to `Y`. What does it mean for `X*` and `Y*`? *Absolutely nothing whatsoever*. They are unrelated types. Same thing with pointers to members.

Comment: Say, the rest of Test implements a dictionary-like interface where keys are string objects and values are all Base* (or pointers to Base derivatives). Thus for these few fixed fields I would like to extend the dictionary-like interface with some predefined string keys. When a value for the "size" key is asked I would give out the value of that `size` member, and give it out as Base*.

Comment: Then why not use an actual map? As in `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Base>> value = { { "size", std::make_unique<Size>() }, ... };`.

Comment: Well, the map is already there. But it can be quite large. The only expected merit from this attempt was simplifying future debugging when some map fileds are already in the debugger scope when looking at a Test object, without the need to go through the map.

Comment: Even assuming you will hack around and have some `T& Test::get(std::string key);`, the `T` type needs to be known at compile type, you cannot just `test.get("more") = whatever;`, c++ is not python. Then you might try to use `std::variant<Bool, Size, More> Test::get(std::string key);`, but that will only complicate your solution. It seems you are going in a wrong direction, so would be better to explain what you are trying to solve.

Comment: There is a conversion from `Bool*` to `Base*`, but  there is no conversion from `Bool**` to `Base**`, which is a similar construct.

Comment: @molbdnilo This may look similar, but I believe they are actually totally different. For pointer-to-pointer, the conversion is forbidden for logical reasons, while here, I see no reason to forbid it. If you do see such a reason (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8026040/509868)), please post an answer!

Comment: @anatolyg No, it is the same principle - adding a layer of indirection - and the same logical reason. `Base* Test::* fields = &Test::flag; Test t; t.*fields = t.size;` would make `t.flag` point to a `Size`.

Comment: @molbdnilo "point to the `size` member" - pretty much OK by me as they all are Base*. I would use them as the pointer to the base class. And for more I have the  ways to learn the exact derived class. But it would not let me the very first `Base* Test::* fields = &Test::flag;`...

Comment: @Outtruder No, `flag` is a `Bool*`, not a `Base*`. If you overwrite it with a `Size*`, you're in big trouble.

Comment: @molbdnilo Who said I need to write to those pointers? The intention was to get Base* from them :) OK, I give up. There are other ways...

Comment: @Outtruder Nobody said that you need to, but the validity of the conversion does not depend on what you do afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

While one can convert `Bool*` to `Base*`, `Bool**` to `const Bool *const*` (though not to `const Bool**`), and `Bool *Test::*` to `const Bool *const Test::*` (though not to `const Bool *Test::*`), you can't convert `Bool**` even to `const Base *const*` or `Bool *Test::*` to `const Base *Test::*` because with multiple inheritance pointer conversions can require **offsets** be applied to the pointer value and there's no way of encoding those in the pointer (to member).  That wouldn't matter in this particular case, of course, but the language rule is general.

A practical workaround for the read-only case is to create an array (or other structure) of **function pointers**:

```
class Test {
public:
    Bool* flag;
    Size* size;
    More* data;
private:
    template<auto P>
    static Base* get(const Test *t) {return t->*P;}
    static inline Base* (*fields[])(const Test*)=
        {get<&Test::flag>,get<&Test::size>,get<&Test::data>};
};
```