# ‘base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘deriv’

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why is base inaccessible to `deriv` inside `deriv`? The program compiles with `class deriv : public base`.

```
#include <cstdio>

class base
{
};

class deriv : base
{
  public:
  void f(deriv, int){printf("deriv::f(deriv, int)\n");}
  void f(base){printf("deriv::f(base)\n");}
};

int main()
{
  deriv d;
  d.f(d);
}

17: error: ‘base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘deriv’
17: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void deriv::f(base)’
```

Because two people got it wrong already, I will ask in bold: **why does `base` need to be publicly inherited**? It is accessed from within `deriv` only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be incorrectly assuming that conversion from `deriv` to `base` when calling `deriv::f(base)` occurs "inside `deriv`" and thus has to be accessible. This is not the case. When you call a function, all conversions necessary for initializing function's arguments occur in the caller's context. They are not "inside `derive`". They happen in the "outside world". And in your case the "outside world" has no access to `deriv`-to-`base` conversion.

In your specific case it is `main` that is trying to convert `deriv` to `base`. And `main` cannot do it since it has no access to the private base of `deriv`. Just to experiment you can declare `int main()` as a friend of `deriv` and the code will compile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I right to suspect that this is a rather rough protection of privacy done by compiler? I understand that private class inheritance breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). This makes the outcome a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: `main` does have access to `base`, but not to `base` through `deriv`. `deriv` does have access to `base`. very well, it is my fault that I used `private` inheritance ... :-)

Comment: Trying to understand this behaviour, I imagined that the compiler treats privately inherited classes as it treats private members. This was not satisfactory for me, and it finally has dawned on me that the compiler takes a simple opportunistic approach: it regards access specifiers as "gateways". In main, a privately inherited base class is not accessible through conversion from a derived class. This also applies to pointers to and pointers to pointers to those classes, I believe.

Comment: @Doru Georgescu: You are correct about pointers (and references), but "pointers to pointers" do not belong here. "Pointers to pointers" is a completely different story. `deriv **` is not convertible to `base **` even if `base` is a *public* base class. Also, base classes are indeed analogous to data members. Bases and data members are all *subobjects* of the complete object. The access syntax for bases is different from access syntax for data members, but in many other respects they are very similar.

Comment: Indeed, base classes are similar to data members, and the "gateway" rule applies to them, too. However, on the issue of deriv ** I hope that you are joking, right? Please tell me what happens, a link or at least a keyword ...

Comment: Very well, I found these: [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532422/conversion-of-pointer-to-pointer-between-derived-and-base-classes) and [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026040/conversion-from-derived-to-base). In my opinion, polymorphism breaks encapsulation and too much of it ruins the OOP. That's the reason why `deriv **` can't be converted automatically to `base **`, and nobody wants to clearly state it.

Answer (score 6):

If you define a class with the `class` keyword, then members and base classes are private by default.

If the base class needs to be public, then either explicitly declare it `public` (as you mention in the question), or use the `struct` keyword which makes things public by default.

> why does base need to be public?

In this case, your call to `f(base)` requires a conversion from `deriv` to `base`, and such a conversion is only possible if the base class is accessible. Being private, it is not accessible in `main`, which is where the conversion is required.

Comment: Why does it need to be public?

Comment: @DoruGeorgescu: I've updated the answer: conversion to a base class is only allowed if the base class is accessible.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: *"Being private, it is not accessible in main"*. I think the conversion is not possible anywhere, even in the member functions of either of the classes.

Comment: @DoruGeorgescu otherwise you can not access the base class (like you are trying to do)

Comment: @Nawaz: Why do you think that? Private members and base classes are accessible to members and friends; that's what "private" means. So the conversion is certainly possible in a member of `deriv`, as demonstrated [here](http://ideone.com/XrXs9E).

Answer (score 3):

Because it is privately inherited :

```
class deriv : base
```

The default inheritance for `class` is private, meaning other classes and functions do not have access to the base class of the derived class.

---

There is a small problem in your example. This :

```
  deriv d;
  d.f(d);
```

is not going to do what you expect it to do because of slicing.

If we fix the above problem by changing the signature of the `f` to this :

```
void f(base&){printf("deriv::f(base)\n");}
```

there is still a problem accessing the base class of `deriv`, because it inherited privately from the base.

Comment: @DoruGeorgescu In your specific example, it is `main` that can not convert `deriv` to `base`. Better wording might be needed :)