# Pass derived** as base**

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class Fruit {};
class Apple : public Fruit {};
class Banana : public Fruit {};

Apple** apples;
Banana** bananas;

void reportAboutFruit(Fruit** fruits);
```

When I try `reportAboutFruit(apples);` I get a compiler error, `error: invalid conversion from 'Apple**' to 'Fruit**'`.

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026040/conversion-from-derived-to-base) why it would be dangerous to allow `reportAboutFruit()` to change the data, but as the function name implies I only want to read it, and I only need the stuff contained in the base `Fruit` class.

I am by no means a C++ expert, can someone explain how I can make this work?

Comment: `type**` is usually a red-flag design-wise in C++

Comment: why don't you use 'reportAboutFruit(Fruit* fruits)'?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532422/conversion-of-pointer-to-pointer-between-derived-and-base-classes