# Casting to a ptr to ptr of derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, casting

Why do I get a compilation error if I don't specify an explicit cast to Base** ?

Can I use a pointer to pointer when I deal with a derived class?

```
class Base { };
class Child : public Base { };

void SomeFunction(Base** ppoObj) {}
void SomeFunction(Base* poObj) {}

int main()
{   
    Child *c = new Child();

    // This passed.
    SomeFunction(c);
    SomeFunction((Base**)&c);

    // CompilationError
    SomeFunction(&c);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you can implicitly cast `Child*` to `Base*`, there's no implicit cast from `Child**` to `Base**`, because it could be used to violate type-safety.  Consider:

```
class Base { };
class Child1 : public Base { };
class Child2 : public Base { };

int main() {
    Child1 *c = new Child1();
    Base **cp = &c;  // If this were allowed...
    *cp = new Child2();  // ...then this could happen.  (*cp is a Base*)
}
```

[More information in the C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#derivedptrptr-to-baseptrptr)

Comment: My program working well when I use SomeFunction((Base**)&c).
Which problem may appear at run time? @Wyzard

Comment: Right, there's just no *implicit* cast.  Your explicit cast overrides the compiler's type-checking — just like you can cast a `Child1*` to a `Child2*` even though they're unrelated types.  Casting `Child**` to `Base**` should be OK as long as you only assign pointers to compatible types (i.e. don't do what I did in the example).

Answer (score 1):

> Why I got an compilation error if I don't specify a casting to `Base**`?

Because `Child**` is not implicitly convertible to `Base**`.

> Can I use pointer to pointer when I deal with derived class?

If by that you mean "Can I assign `Child**` to a variable of `Base**` type", then the answer is: No, you can not.

Answer (score 1):

`Child` is a derived class of `Base`, but `Child*` is not a derived class of `Base*`.

If the compiler did allow you automatic conversion of pointer-to-pointers, you would get the following bad example (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532428/2079934) running:

```
Child *c = new Child;
Base **bb = &c;
*bb = new Base;
```

`c` now points to a `Base`, not to a `Child`.

Comment: *"Child\* is not a derived class of Base\*"* is vacuously true since pointers aren't class types at all :)

Comment: Since the Q&A you link to is a perfect target for this thread to be marked as dupe to, consider next time when you know of such dupe target thread to propose a (possible) dupe target rather than needlessy duplicating the dupe target's information in the dupe.